# How can I check two conditions in an if statement?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

```
<%
i=1
j=1

if ((i=1) && (j=1)) then
response.write("i = 1 and j =1")
else
response.write("i <> 0")
end if

%>
```

I'm saving this with a `.asp` extension. Here the `if` condition is not working. How can I check 2 conditions in `if` condition of classic ASP code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [logical operator](http://www.landofcode.com/asp-tutorials/asp-operators.php) you're looking for is `And` in this case:

```
if ((i = 1) And (j = 1)) then
```

Comment: Is there a way to do an 'or' in the statement? Like `if((user=admin) or (user=employee))`?

Comment: @NicolasV: Did you try and find out?

Answer (score 1):

The operator is `and` not `&&` so change your code to:

```
<%
i=1
j=1

if ((i=1) and (j=1)) then
Response.Write("i = 1 and j =1")
else
Response.Write("i <> 0")
end if

%>
```

---

Output:

> i = 1 and j =1

Comment: Is there a way to do an 'or' in the statement? Like `if((user=admin) or (user=employee))`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ((i=1) and (j=1)) then
```